# How do I match for a missing word in mysql with regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I am struggling with regular expressions in mysql. Since there is are no positive/negative lookbehinds/aheads how can I search for string that doesn't contain a specific substring?
I build a regex that would work fine in PCRE and looks like this

```
/* example where it should match entry 1:
entry 1: ...lorem ipsum [table mode="foo" offset="1"] dolor sit...
entry 2: ...lorem ipsum dolor sit...
entry 3: ...lorem ipsum [table language="en" mode="foo"] dolor sit...
*/    
'\[table.*(?<=language).*\]'
```

How can I achieve the same in MYSQL?

Comment: Use NOT REGEXP.

Comment: I don't know how this should help since I don't want to invert the regex? I still want to find the places where '[table...]' is present. When I write NOT REGEXP I will have everything except the '[table...]' matches.

Comment: Use 2 conditions. 1st - `REGEXP '\[table.*'`, 2nd - `NOT REGEXP '\[table[^]]+language'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
WHERE col NOT REGEXP '\\[table[^][]*language' AND col LIKE '%[table %'
```

The `NOT REGEXP '\\[table[^][]*language'` condition makes sure there is no `[table` tag with `language` word inside in the record and the `LIKE '%[table %'` condition matches a record that contains `[table`  string.

Regex details:

- `\[table` - `[table`
- `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `language`  - a literal string

If you are using MySQL v8+, you can use

```sql
WHERE col REGEXP '^(?!.*\\[table\\b[^\\]\\[]*language).*\\[table\\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3l1V0z/3). Note that in ICU regex syntax, both `[` and `]` are special inside square brackets.